# what is spring ioc container?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have read many answers on the internet so far but still could not get a visual understanding of the container spring.
I would appreciate it if you could give me a visual understanding of what exactly it does

Answer (score 0):

imagine a pool . for using any base objects or configurations in spring you don't need to create new instance of them or create a class for each of them and make this object singleton for just creating once . you just create a bean of this objects and put them into a pool . when you need to use this object just injecting them into you classes and spring will use the beans that are in the pool.